# perl: passing subroutines rexexp replace with search results

Tags: regex, perl, parameters, subroutine

i have the following perl subroutine:

```
sub rep {

 defined ($filein = shift) || die ("no filein");
 defined ($fileout = shift) || die ("no fileout");
 $look = shift;
 $replace = shift;
 open (infile, "$filein")|| die;
 open (outfile, "> $fileout")|| die;
 while (<infile>) {
   s/$look/$replace/g;
   print outfile;
 }
(close the files)
}
```

and the following text:

```
kuku(fred) foo(3)
kuku(barney) foo(198)
```

i want to call it with the following structures:

```
$look = kuku\((\w+)\) foo \((\d+)\),
$replace = gaga\(($1)\) bar\(($2)\).
```

but when i called the sub with the following (and it's variations), i couldn't make it accept the $1, $2 format:

```
&rep ($ARGV[0], $ARGV[1], 
    "kuku\\(\(\\w+\)\\) foo \\(\(\\d+\)\\)" , 
    "gaga\\(\(\$1\)\\) bar\\(\(\$2\)\\)");
```

all i get is:

```
gaga($1) bar($2)
gaga($1) bar($2)
```

what am i doing wrong? 
how can i make the subroutine identify the $1\ $2 (...) as the search results of the search and replace?

Comment: What you are doing wrong? For a start, you don't use strict and you don't use warnings and your "perl" looks like it's 1999.

Comment: sorry mom, i'll try not to do it again...

Comment: Not good enough son, go to your room!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if substitution part in regex can be set in a way you want it without using eval `/e`, so this is how I would write this.

`qr//` parameter is real regex, followed by callback in which `$_[0]` is `$1`

```
rep( $ARGV[0], $ARGV[1], qr/kuku\((\w+)\) foo \((\d+)\)/, sub { "gaga($_[0]) bar($_[1])" } );

sub rep {

  my ($filein, $fileout, $look, $replace) = @_;
  defined $filein or die "no filein";
  defined $fileout or die "no fileout";

  open (my $infile, "<", $filein) or die $!;
  open (my $outfile, ">", $fileout) or die $!;

  while (<$infile>) {
    s/$look/$replace->($1,$2)/ge;
    print $outfile;
  }
  # (close the files)
}
```

This could be even more simplified by just passing callback which would change `$_`.

```
rep( $ARGV[0], $ARGV[1], sub { s|kuku\((\w+)\) foo \((\d+)\)|gaga($1) bar($2)| } );

sub rep {

  my ($filein, $fileout, $replace) = @_;
  defined $filein or die "no filein";
  defined $fileout or die "no fileout";

  open (my $infile, "<", $filein) or die $!;
  open (my $outfile, ">", $fileout) or die $!;

  while (<$infile>) {
    $replace->();
    print $outfile;
  }
  # (close the files)
}
```

Comment: well mpapec, this works (i still trying to figure out how... :-) ).

Comment: first one, or second example? both are using anonymous function aka callback.

Comment: just checked the second, it also works (and in fact - i like it better!). thanks a lot.